# How to get list to store views collection along with stores in magento2

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-view, stores, store-switcher

I have two stores **Sweeden and France** and two storeviews for each **sweedish,english** and **french,english** respectively.

i.e

> Store Sweeden(SE) has two Storeviews Sweedish(se) and English(se_en)
>
> Store France(FR) has two Storeviews French(fr) and English(fr_en)

**I'm trying to get the list of stores collection in the frontend**.

But I'm getting storeviews details directly.

```
1-default
0-admin
2-se
3-en
4-fr
5-fr_en
```

This is the code I used to get stores collection

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->create("\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface");
$stores = $storeManager->getStores(true, false);
foreach($stores as $store){
echo $store->getId()."-".$store->getCode()."<br>";
//echo $store->getAll();
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to inject `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` class in your construct. Try to use this below code.

```
protected $_storeManager;
public function __construct(
    ................
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    ................
) {
    ................
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    ................
}
public function yourFunction()
{
    $groups = $this->_storeManager->getWebsite()->getGroups();
    $storeName = [];
    $storeViewName = [];
    foreach ($groups as $key => $group) {
        $storeName[] = $group->getName(); // get store name
        $stores = $group->getStores();
        foreach ($stores as $store) {
            $storeViewName[] = $store->getName(); // get store view name
        }
    }
    print_r($storeViewName);
    print_r($storeName);
}
```

Clean cache and check output.

Comment: HI @Rohan May I know from where I can get that $groups in your code.Thanks

Comment: Oh sorry. I forgot to add it.

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: HI @Rohan Thanks for the update.I'll check and let you know.

Comment: Is it working for you ? Please accpet and upvote answer so other user can also use this answer :)

Comment: Hi @Rohan Thanks for the patience.I am geting the response.

Array ( [0] => French [1] => Main Website Store [2] => Sweeden ) 
Array ( [0] => French [1] => English [2] => Default Store View [3] => Sweedish [4] => English )
But can I the connection between the stores and storeviews I mean how can I map them.

Comment: Okay. I will update my answer and inform you.

Comment: Okay @Rohan Hapani.Will wait for your update.